# Fake subdirectory masking index.html file with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I have simple one page website, with following structure:

```
.
├── js
|   └── something.js
├── css
|   └── style.css
├── index.html
└── index-en.html
```

I want that index-en.html is seen as "fake" sub-directory "en", so that English index (index-en.html) is visible as domain.com/en/.

Comment: And what is the problem with real sub-directory "en" ?

Comment: Nothing special, except that you need to change all the *.css, *.js and *.jpg files calls. I though that there may be some more elegant way to solve this using htaccess.

Comment: It's the same with rewrite. You just need to add `<base href="/">` in all your html pages or use absolute links